# How do I make a SINGLE legend using subplots? _get_legend_handles_labels is not working

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, legend

I want to make a *single* legend with corresponding colors for the models that are in the individual plots on the whole subplot.

My current code is as follows:

```
from matplotlib.legend import _get_legend_handles_labels

colors = ['red', 'blue','darkblue', 'purple', 'orange', 'brown', 'pink', 'darkgreen', 'gray']
models = ['Logistic Regression', 'SVM', 'Decision Tree', 'Random Forest', 'XGBoost', 'ADABoost', 'Gaussian NB', 'KNN', 'MLP']

# English

fig, axs = plt.subplots(4,2, figsize=(25,15))
fig.suptitle('Performance measures for English and Arabic data', fontsize = 25)

axs[0,0].bar(models, en_f1_scores, color=colors)
axs[0,0].set_title("English F1 score", fontsize = 20)

axs[1,0].bar(models, en_acc_scores, color=colors)
axs[1,0].set_title("English accuracy score", fontsize = 20)

axs[2,0].bar(models, en_recall_scores, color=colors)
axs[2,0].set_title("English recall score", fontsize = 20)

axs[3,0].bar(models, en_precision_scores, color=colors)
axs[3,0].set_title("English precision score", fontsize = 20)

# Arabic

axs[0,1].bar(models, ar_f1_scores, color=colors)
axs[0, 1].set_title("Arabic F1 score", fontsize = 20)

axs[1,1].bar(models, ar_accuracy_scores, color=colors)
axs[1,1].set_title("Arabic accuracy score", fontsize = 20)

axs[2,1].bar(models, ar_recall_scores, color=colors)
axs[2,1].set_title("Arabic recall score", fontsize = 20)

axs[3,1].bar(models, ar_precision_scores, color=colors)
axs[3,1].set_title("Arabic precision score", fontsize = 20)

fig.tight_layout(pad=3.0)
```

And the current output looks like this:

[image: Current outplot subplots]

Adding this code:

```
lines, labels = fig.axes[-1].get_legend_handles_labels()
fig.legend(lines, labels, loc = 'upper center')
```

Does not do anything, all it shows me is:

> <matplotlib.legend.Legend at 0x266574402b0>

Moreover, both *lines* and *labels* are empty arrays; **[]**

What can I do to add a legend at the top of the subplot figure? (if it is a horizontal legend, even better!)

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you want to appear in the legend?  Just repeating the x-labels and bar colors into the legend seems superfluous, as that information is already written 8 times in the plot. Adding it a 9th time just makes the plot harder to understand.  Or do you want to remove the labels in the individual bars?  If you create the subplots as `plt.subplots(...., sharex=True)`, matplotlib will leave out the x-labels everywhere except the lower row. Then the lower row can serve as the legend and make the plot lighter.

Comment: I should have specified, my excuses. I do want to add the legend to avoid having the labels repeated 8 times as you say. I will for sure add the sharex parameter. That leaves the question on how to make the legend, still. The procedure from the code in my post did not work.  I would appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would suggest to save all information into lists, so the plot can be made via a large loop. That way, if some detail changes, it only needs to be changed at one spot.

To create a legend, graphical elements that have a "label" will be added automatically.  Normally, a complete bar plot only gets one label. By diving into the generated bars, individual labels can be assigned.

The code first creates a dummy legend, so `fig.tight_layout()` can adapt all the spacings and leave some place for the legend. After calling `fig.tight_layout()`, the real legend is created. (With the real legend, `fig.tight_layout()` would try to assign it completely to one subplot, and create a wide gap between the two columns of subplots).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

colors = ['red', 'blue', 'darkblue', 'purple', 'orange', 'brown', 'pink', 'darkgreen', 'gray']
models = ['Logistic Regression', 'SVM', 'Decision Tree', 'Random Forest', 'XGBoost', 'ADABoost', 'Gaussian NB', 'KNN', 'MLP']

titles = ["F1 score", "accuracy score", "recall score", "precision score"]

N = len(models)
en_f1_scores = np.random.rand(N)
en_acc_scores = np.random.rand(N)
en_recall_scores = np.random.rand(N)
en_precision_scores = np.random.rand(N)
en_scores = [en_f1_scores, en_acc_scores, en_recall_scores, en_precision_scores]
ar_f1_scores = np.random.rand(N)
ar_acc_scores = np.random.rand(N)
ar_recall_scores = np.random.rand(N)
ar_precision_scores = np.random.rand(N)
ar_scores = [ar_f1_scores, ar_acc_scores, ar_recall_scores, ar_precision_scores]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(4, 2, figsize=(25, 15), sharex=True, sharey='row')
fig.suptitle('Performance measures for English and Arabic data', fontsize=25)

for axs_row, en_score, ar_score, title in zip(axs, en_scores, ar_scores, titles):
    for language, score, ax in zip(['English', 'Arabic'], [en_score, ar_score], axs_row):
        ax.bar(models, score, color=colors)
        ax.set_title(language + ' ' + title, fontsize=20)
        ax.set_xticks([])  # remove the x tick and their labels
        ax.grid(axis='y', ls=':', color='black')  # add some gridlines
        ax.set_axisbelow(True)  # gridlines behind the bars
        for spine in ['top', 'right', 'left']:  # remove part of the surrounding box, as it gets busy with the grid lines
            ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False)
        ax.margins(x=0.01)  # less white space left and right

# the legend is created for each graphical element that has a "label"
for bar, model in zip(axs[0, 0].containers[0], models):
    bar.set_label(model)
# first create a dummy legend, so fig.tight_layout() makes enough space
axs[0, 0].legend(handles=axs[0, 0].containers[0][:1],
                 bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1.12), loc='lower left')
fig.tight_layout(pad=3.0)
# now create the real legend; if fig.tight_layout() were called on this,
#  it would create a large empty space between the columns of subplots
#  as it wants the legend to belong to only one of the subplots
axs[0, 0].legend(handles=axs[0, 0].containers[0], ncol=len(models),
                 bbox_to_anchor=(1.03, 1.12), loc='lower center', fontsize=18)
plt.show()
```

[image: common legend for 8 subplots]

Comment: Thank you so much! If you do not mind, a short follow up question. Is using a for-loop to go over every plot we want to make the norm when creating subplots? Is my method less preferred?

Comment: In Python, using `for` loops (and `zip` etc.) are strongly recommended.  That way, if you want to change some detail to the subplots (e.g. removing the box), you only have to write that code once.  It is called the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and especially Python has a lot of functionality to make this possible.